# how to replace \ by \\ in tcl script string variable?

Tags: tcl

I am trying to replace the `\` with `\\` in a string variable which contains a network folder path. script is

```
regsub -all {'\'} $folderpath {\\} $folderpath
```

if it is other character i am able to replace, since its `\`, I am getting problem.

Comment: Can you give a sample input, what you get out, and what you wanted? Also any error messages that were produced.

Comment: 1. You're enclosing \ within single quotes - that's incorrect. Remove it. 2. \ is an escape character. To treat that as a regular character you need to escape it with another \, so you use an extra \ per \. regsub -all {\\} $folderpath {\\\\} folderpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set folderpath [string map {\\ \\\\} $s]
```

is about five times faster than using `regsub`.

Note that the `file` command has several subcommands that can manage a path string regardless of what the separators look like.

Documentation:
[file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
% set path {C:\Dinesh\Downloads\Movies\Friends}
C:\Dinesh\Downloads\Movies\Friends
% regsub -all {\\} $path {\\\\}
C:\\Dinesh\\Downloads\\Movies\\Friends
%
```